# Is there an equivalent for the 'content' rule that works on elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to apply the `content` rule to an element that isn't a pseudo element:

css:

```
#element {
    content: 'foobs'
}
```

html:

```
<div id = '#element'></div>
```

I then wish to retrieve the computed style via javascript:

javascript:

```
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.body, '#element').content ) //=> 'foobs';
```

This works perfectly when using a pseudo element instead of `#element`, but I want to use a real element for compatibility reasons (IE7 +).

**In short, an alternative to the content rule that works on true elements.**

Comment: What are `pseudo element`s?

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock, I've only known them as selectors. Now I know.

Comment: Why not to add content to a pseudo element of this element, e.g. `#element:after`? All popular browsers (including IE8+) support them.

Comment: Alternatively, you can simply use `document.getElementById('element').innerHTML`, it works everywhere.

Comment: @Ilya Streltsyn Nice approach but I want IE7+. Updated question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't one; the `content` property is only applicable to the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements. Especially if you're looking to set content on elements programmatically "for compatibility reasons" and `::before`/`::after` is not available, you won't find such a solution with CSS. In such a case, you will have much better luck using JavaScript or a server-side solution than using CSS for *a lot* of other things, not just generated content.

Comment: Are there no css rules that allow me to associate a string with an element at all?

Comment: @Starkers: No, there aren't.